# Android Auto deletes Bluetooth connection

Tags: bluetooth, android-auto

Since I started using Android Auto in my Mercedes-Benz, it has been very annoying that the Android Auto app on my Samsung Galaxy S21 frequently deletes the Bluetooth connection to the car. When the Bluetooth connection to the car is deleted, you get no audio in the car speakers on in- or outgoing phone calls. This is a major drawback of Android Auto.

Searching on the internet reveals that this is a common problem for Android Auto users. Many people propose solutions like clearing the cache or data for the app, clearing cache or data of Bluetooth, or deleting the Bluetooth profile of your phone on the car etc. But none of the proposed solutions are permanent.

Can anyone come up with a permanent solution instead of canceling Android Auto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a permanent solution to the problem:

Never plug the USB cable into your Android phone before turning on the ignition of your car and the Bluetooth connection between your car and your phone has been established. When the Bluetooth connection has been established, you can plug the USB cable into your phone.

Following this procedure, Android Auto never deletes the Bluetooth connection between your car and your phone.